# Remove Dashes but Not Hyphens

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove `dashes` before, after, and between spaced words, but not hyphenated words.

> This- -is - a test-sentence. -Test- --- One-Two--Three---Four----.

should become:

> This is a test-sentence. Test One-Two--Three---Four.

Remove multiple dashes `---`.
Keep multiple hyphens `Three---Four`.

---

I was trying to do it with this:

http://rextester.com/SXQ57185

```
string sentence = "This- -is - a test-sentence. -Test- --- One-Two--Three---Four----.";

string regex = @"(?<!\w)\-(?!\-)|(?<!\-)\-(?!\w)";
sentence = Regex.Replace(sentence, regex, "");

Console.WriteLine(sentence);
```

But the output is:

> This is  a test-sentence. Test - One-TwoThree-Four--.

Comment: May be something like [`-+(?=\s+|\.)|(?<=\s+|\.)-+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%2b%28%3f%3d%5cs%2b%7c%5c.%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5cs%2b%7c%5c.%29-%2b&i=This-+-is+-+a+test-sentence.+-Test-+---+One-Two--Three---Four----.&r=)

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815286/3832970) with a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would recommend doing is a combination of both a positive lookback and a positive lookahead against the characters that you **don't** want the dashes to be next to. In your case, that would be spaces and full stops. If **either**  the lookbehind or lookahead match, you want to remove that dash.

This would be: `((?<=[\s\.])\-+)|(\-+(?=[\s\.]))`.

Breaking this down:

- `((?<=[\s\.])\-+)` - match hyphens that follow either a space or a full stop
- `|` - or
- `(\-+(?=[\s\.])` - match hyphens that are followed by either a space or a full stop

Here's a JavaScript example showcasing that:

```js
const string = 'This- -is - a test-sentence. -Test- --- One-Two--Three---Four----.';
const regex = /((?<=[\s\.])\-+)|(\-+(?=[\s\.]))/g;
console.log(string.replace(regex, ''));
```

And this can also been seen on **[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Ct8OJb/1)**.

Note that you'll probably also want to trim the excess spaces after using this, which can simply be done with **[`.Trim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)** in C#.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\b|\s` for this task.

[`/(\b|\s)(-{3})(\b|\s)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/AaVSRR/1)

**[DEMO](https://ideone.com/1UeCwg)**

**Breakdown** shamelessly copied from regex101.com:

`/(\b|\s)(-{3})(\b|\s)/g`

- 1st Capturing Group `(\b|\s)`

  - 1st Alternative `\b`

    - `\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
  - 2nd Alternative \s

    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
- 2nd Capturing Group `(-{3})`

  - `-{3}` matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
  - `{3}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times
- 3rd Capturing Group `(\b|\s)`

  - 1st Alternative `\b`

    - `\b` assert position at a word boundary `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`
  - 2nd Alternative `\s`

    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

Answer (score 1):

You may just match all hyphens in between word chars, and remove all others with a simple

```
Regex.Replace(s, @"\b(-+)\b|-", "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%28-%2B%29%5Cb%7C-&i=This-%20-is%20-%20a%20test-sentence.%20-Test-%20---%20One-Two--Three---Four----.&r=%241)

**Details**

- `\b(-+)\b` - word boundary, followed with 1+ hyphens, and then again a word boundary (that is, hyphen(s) in between letters, digits and underscores)
- `|` - or
- `-` - a hyphen in other contexts (it will be removed).

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/PeJFkJ):

```
var s = "This- -is - a test-sentence. -Test- --- One-Two--Three---Four----.";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"\b(-+)\b|-", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(result); 
// => This is  a test-sentence. Test  One-Two--Three---Four.
```